# Laravel get_file_contents() replaces & with &amp;

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, escaping, file-get-contents

How can I avoid Laravel replacing `&` with `&amp;` when calling `get_file_contents()`? I always get a "Bad Request" response because of this,
which is not a problem when not using Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

use `file_get_contents(htmlspecialchars_decode($URL));`

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem just use the `"` instead `'` when building string URL path like follow:

```
 public function __construct($url, $username, $password)
{
    $this->url = $url;
    $this->params  = 'send?username='.$username.'&password='.$password.'&dlr=no';
}
```

to:

```
 public function __construct($url, $username, $password)
{
    $this->url = $url;
    $this->params  = "send?username=".$username."&password=".$password."&dlr=no";
}
```

Instead of use `file_get_contents()` you can use `guzzlehttp/guzzle` you can use this [link](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/overview.html#installation) for installation, and following example to send request and get response:

```
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => $this->url,
    'timeout' => 1.0,
]);
$request = $client->request('POST', $params);
$response = $request->getBody()->getContents();
```

You can access the content's of body by `getContents()` method, hop this help you.